# Puzzling Python I/O error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: file-io, python-3.x

I'm trying to grab an XML file from a server (*using Python 3.2.3*), but I keep getting this error that there's "no such file or directory". I'm sure the URL is correct, since it outputs the URL in the error message, and I can copy-n-paste it and load it in my browser. So I'm very puzzled how this could be happening. Here's my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

class Blah(object):

    def getXML(self,xmlurl):
        tree = etree.parse(xmlurl)
        return tree.getroot()

    def pregameData(self,url):
        try:
            x = self.getXML('{0}linescore.xml'.format(url))
        except IOError as err:
            x = "I/O error: {0}".format(err)
        return x


if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = Blah()
    l = ['http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2013/month_04/day_15/gid_2013_04_15_anamlb_minmlb_1/',
         'http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2013/month_04/day_15/gid_2013_04_15_phimlb_cinmlb_1/',
         'http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2013/month_04/day_15/gid_2013_04_15_slnmlb_pitmlb_1/'
        ]
    for url in l:
        pre = x.pregameData(url)
        print(pre)
```

And it always returns this error:

```
I/O error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2013/month_04/day_15/gid_2013_04_15_anamlb_minmlb_1/linescore.xml'
I/O error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2013/month_04/day_15/gid_2013_04_15_phimlb_cinmlb_1/linescore.xml'
I/O error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2013/month_04/day_15/gid_2013_04_15_slnmlb_pitmlb_1/linescore.xml'
```

You can copy-n-paste those URL's and see the files do exist in those locations. I even  copied the files & directories to localhost, and tried this as localhost in case the foreign server had some kind of block. It gave me the same errors, so that's not an issue. I wondered if [Etree's parse()](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) can't handle HTTP, but the documentation doesn't say anything about that, so I'm guessing that's not an issue either.

**UPDATE:** As suggested in the comments, I went with using `open()`, but it still returned the error. Importing & trying [urllib.request.urlopen(url)](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) returns an error that *AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, `xml.etree` dosen't automatically download and parse urls, if you want to do that you'll need to download it yourself first (using urllib or requests...).

The documentation explicitly states that [`parse`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) takes a filename or fileobject, if it would support an url i'm sure it would say so explicitly. [`lxml.etree.parse()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#parse) for example does.

Comment: Aaahhh thanks. I think of URL's as being locations of files & directories, so I figured that a URL wouldn't be different than a  fileobject. I'll have to start tweakin' my thinkin' on that. You rawwk!

Comment: Oddly, that didn't fix it after all. When I changed the loop code to `pre = open(url)`, it still returns the same error.

Comment: `open()` doesn't open urls, it opens a file on the local drive. try `from urllib import request; pre = request.urlopen(url); ...`

Comment: Ok, cool. Now it's working. I was gettin' quite confused. Thanks! One more step out of Python newbie-ville thanks to you :-)